# Incorrectly setting module template variable

Tags: templating, craft3, variable, modules

Getting error:

> Calling unknown method:
>   craft\web\twig\variables\CraftVariable::markAsReadModule()

Trying to use a template variable that I created in my Craft 3 module, I use this module for other things that work as expected but I am running into an issue with this in the template:

```
{{ craft.markAsReadModule.read(entry.id) }}
```

In the init method for `craft/modules/markasreadmodule/MarkAsReadModule.php` I register the variable:

I am using:

```
use craft\web\twig\variables\CraftVariable;
use modules\markasreadmodule\variables\MarkAsReadModuleVariable;
```

Then I have this in the init:

```
Event::on(
    CraftVariable::class,
    CraftVariable::EVENT_INIT,
    function (Event $event) {
        /** @var CraftVariable $variable */
        $variable = $event->sender;
        $variable->set('markAsReadModule', MarkAsReadModuleVariable::class);
    }
);
```

In `craft/modules/markasreadmodule/variables/MarkAsReadModuleVariable.php`

```
public function read($entryId)
{
    $service = new MarkAsRead(); // initialize the service class
    $read = $service->read($entryId);
}
```

I suspect I am setting the naming convention where I include it in the template and/or in the init method within `craft/modules/markasreadmodule/MarkAsReadModule.php`

Comment: Not seeing anything obviously wrong... are you sure your module is being bootstrapped/loaded?

Comment: I goofed on the bootstrap array in the app.php config, thanks.

Comment: Glad you're sorted... would you mind adding your solution as an official answer? Might end up helping someone in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Was running into the same problem today. I was able to access the controller and the service, but none of the variables. Looks like Brad was able to fix the problem but didn't add a final solution.

I wasn't registering any variables on the `init()` function. Adding the last line of code registered the variable but did not load it onto every request.

```
    // Register our variables
    Event::on(
        CraftVariable::class,
        CraftVariable::EVENT_INIT,
        function (Event $event) {
            /** @var CraftVariable $variable */
            $variable = $event->sender;
            $variable->set('formSenderModule', FormSenderModuleVariable::class);
        }
    );
```

To add it onto every request, I had to add `form-sender-module` into my bootstrap array in `app.php`.

```
'bootstrap' => ['form-sender-module']
```